# Numerical Integration over a column value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a numerical integration on the second column successively until its value matches the third column value. I am not familiar with python, but I wrote a simple code following some online literature just for integration using the Simpson method. I am having doubts about output. I do not it is providing correct values or not. Any help will be appreciated.

input:

```
461.40  180.46  434.63
445.10  172.44  434.63
429.40  195.95  434.63
414.20  185.93  434.63
399.50  244.58  434.63
385.40  351.23  434.63
371.80  261.06  434.63
358.70  330.59  434.63
346.00  344.46  434.63
333.80  327.37  434.63
322.00  388.16  434.63
310.60  513.62  434.63
299.60  402.87  434.63
289.00  584.76  434.63
278.80  524.33  434.63
269.00  559.31  434.63
259.50  492.54  434.63
250.30  627.84  434.63
241.40  674.25  434.63
232.90  688.39  434.63
224.70  874.61  434.63
216.70  922.02  434.63
209.10  923.38  434.63
201.70  1117.23 434.63
194.60  1071.73 434.63
187.70  1277.05 434.63
181.10  1261.93 434.63
174.70  1402.85 434.63
168.50  1548.87 434.63
162.50  1591.24 434.63
156.80  1649.03 434.63
151.20  1746.39 434.63
145.90  1690.46 434.63
140.70  1936.21 434.63
135.80  1799.77 434.63
131.00  2157.43 434.63
126.30  2065.08 434.63
121.90  2017.01 434.63
117.60  2066.25 434.63
113.40  1909.50 434.63
109.40  1681.24 434.63
105.50  1862.53 434.63
101.80  1527.52 434.63
98.20   1604.43 434.63
94.70   1344.15 434.63
91.40   1325.48 434.63
88.20   1163.34 434.63
85.10   1194.12 434.63
82.00   1152.07 434.63
79.10   1069.28 434.63
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

def print_integration(filename='py_input.txt'):

    df=pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

    x=np.array(df[0]/1000)
    y=np.array(df[1])
    length=len(x)
    upper_bound=x[0]
    lower_bound=x[length-1]
    del_x=(upper_bound - lower_bound)/length
    intg=simps(y,dx=del_x)

    print('{}'.format(intg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_integration()
```

Comment: You integration is not quite right because the first column is not equi-distant so you cannot use Simpson's rule (or other simple rules like trapezoid, rectangular) . This is easy enough to fix, but I am confused by this part of your question :' ... successively until its value matches the third column value'. What exactly do you mean? The value of the integral is roughly 306,000 which is a long way away from your third column 434.63

Comment: Yes, I want to perform integrate on second column values row-wise and once it matches I have to stop. It is like I will do integration of the first two rows of the second column and matches with the third column if it does not then I will go for the first three columns and matches and then the first four and so on. I think it is better to say that the integral value should be close to the third column values instead of matches.

Comment: The "integral" of the first two rows of column 2 is basically (461.4 - 445.1) * (180.46 + 172.44)/2 which is ~ 2876 which is already way bigger than the value in column 3. and as you add more rows it keeps getting bigger. what am I missing here?

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. I am sorry I forget to convert the first column values. It is in nanometer and it has to convert in micron before integration. So I have to divide the first column by 1000. Let me correct the above code. Than you.